# Changing variable within document.form1.Q1[n+1].value

Tags: javascript, loops

This is what I have so far:

```
for (var n = 0; n < order.length; n++)
    {                 
        for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) 
            {
                if (order[i]==[n+1])
                    {
                        document.form1.Q1[n+1].value = [i+1];
                    }
            }
    };
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but without knowing how long the array, or the amount of questions in the form will be (though they'll always be equal to each other):

```
if (order[0] == 1)
{ 
document.form1.Q11.value = 1;
}

if (order[1] == 1)
{ 
document.form1.Q11.value = 2;
}

if (order[2] == 1)
{ 
document.form1.Q11.value = 3;
}

if (order[0] == 2)
{ 
document.form1.Q12.value = 1;
}

if (order[1] == 2)
{ 
document.form1.Q12.value = 2;
}

if (order[2] == 2)
{ 
document.form1.Q12.value = 3;
}

if (order[0] == 3)
{ 
document.form1.Q13.value = 1;
}

if (order[1] == 3)
{ 
document.form1.Q13.value = 2;
}

if (order[2] == 3)
{ 
document.form1.Q13.value = 3;
}
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is with inserting the variable [n+1] into:

```
document.form1.Q1[n+1].value = [i+1];
```

I've tried a few different routes but can't seem to figure out how to do it another way, and I obviously can't hard code it.

For example:

```
  for (var n = 0; n < order.length; n++)
    {                 
        var Q = n+1;
        var question = Q.toString(); 
          var string = "Q1" + question;

            for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (order[i]==[n+1])
                        {
                            document.form1.['string'].value = [i+1];
                        }
                }
    };
```

and:

```
document.forms['form-name']['string'].value = [i+1];
```

At this point I've realised I'm in over my head.

Help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: What exactly do you think `order[i]==[n+1]`? Certainly not what you expect it to do.

Comment: [square brackets] creates a new temporary array with a single element. I doubt this is what you want to do, or at least it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @underscore_d - I've been using a different scripting language that uses square brackets as inserts in a loop - hadn't thought about the differences in Javascript! That helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach with the `string` variable was not bad, but you'll have to use it as a variable in the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) - you used the string literal `'string'` which was equivalent to accessing a `.string` property.

```
for (var n = 0; n < order.length; n++) {                 
    var Q = n+1;
    var question = Q.toString(); 
    var string = "Q1" + question;

    for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (order[i] == n+1) { // no array literal here!
            document.form1[string].value = i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, there's a cleaner approach that doesn't need nested loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    var Q = order[i];
    var string = "Q1" + Q;
    document.forms.form1.elements[string].value = i+1;
}
```

Comment: If there is no outer loop, then where does your `i` come from?

Comment: @underscore_d: Oops, screw that, I messed this one up.

Comment: @underscore_d: Fixed now.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I'd reached this from your earlier comments :) Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your input everyone! I've been using another scripting language, so was pulling over the square brackets from that thinking it would work here - oops!

I've got it working now, with:

```
for (var n = 0; n < order.length; n++)
    {                 
        var Q = n+1;
        var question = Q.toString(); 
        var string = "Q1" + question;       

            for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (order[i]==Q)
                        {
                            document.form1[string].value = i+1;
                        }
                }
    };
```

You are all awesome! Thank you :)